# Custom Route Extension, Access Denied

Tags: here-api

I tried to send the example request in the guide on Custom Route Extension API with my app_id and app_code inserted, shown below. I sent it by entering it in my google chrome browser.

```
http://cre.cit.api.here.com/2/overlays/upload.json?map_name=OVERLAYBLOCKROAD&overlay_spec=[{"op":"override","shape":[[50.10765,8.68774],[50.10914,8.68771]],"layer":"LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FCN","data":{"VEHICLE_TYPES":"0"}}]&storage=readonly&app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
```

Indented for readability:

```
http://cre.cit.api.here.com/2/overlays/upload.json?
    map_name=OVERLAYBLOCKROAD&
    overlay_spec=[{"op":"override",
                   "shape":[[50.10765,8.68774],
                            [50.10914,8.68771]],
                   "layer":"LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FCN",
                   "data":{"VEHICLE_TYPES":"0"}}]&
    storage=readonly&
    app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&
    app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
```

But I get this fault code:

```
{"faultCode":"s8c73866c-b4a0-4078-90b7-b4d7529c947d",
 "responseCode": "403",
 "message":"Feature level access has been denied"}
```

Is Custom Route Extension API not available for trial users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On their website under "pricing" you will see that custom route extension is indeed a paid feature.

https://developer.here.com/plans#advanced_features